# Plasmashell won't launch anymore

Tags: linux, configuration, manjaro, plasma

For some reason, when I log in to my box and want to start up plasma, I get the applications started but there's no wallpaper nor panel visible and I also don't get a context menu on right click. Trying to start plasmashell manually gives me:

```
$ plasmashell 
kf.plasma.quick: Applet preload policy set to 1
Qt WebEngine seems to be initialized from a plugin. Please set Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts using QCoreApplication::setAttribute before constructing QGuiApplication.
Attribute Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling must be set before QCoreApplication is created.
Attribute Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling must be set before QCoreApplication is created.
Attribute Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling must be set before QCoreApplication is created.
trying to show an empty dialog
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
trying to show an empty dialog
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CppUtilities::ConversionException'
  what():  unexpected "-" after day
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/bin/plasmashell
KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
KCrash: Application Name = plasmashell path = /usr/bin pid = 4024
KCrash: Arguments: /usr/bin/plasmashell 
kf.plasma.quick: Applet preload policy set to 1
Qt WebEngine seems to be initialized from a plugin. Please set Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts using QCoreApplication::setAttribute before constructing QGuiApplication.
Attribute Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling must be set before QCoreApplication is created.
Attribute Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling must be set before QCoreApplication is created.
Attribute Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling must be set before QCoreApplication is created.
fish: Job 1, 'plasmashell' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
ron@DesktopRon ~ [SIGABRT]> trying to show an empty dialog
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
trying to show an empty dialog
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CppUtilities::ConversionException'
  what():  unexpected "-" after day
```

This definitely seems to be bad:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CppUtilities::ConversionException'
  what():  unexpected "-" after day
```

but I have not been able to fix this yet, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I post this answer rather than deleting this question as reference for others who might run into the same issue:

I found that the problem was caused by `syncthingtray-git` which I'd installed from the `AUR` (https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/syncthingtray-git) after removal (`yay -R syncthingtray-git`), `plasmashell` started perfectly fine, and as expected!